# Package egeloen/http-adapter is abandoned, you should avoid using it, How to fix on composer update

Tags: php, composer-php, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5.1, package

I'm using a PHP Laravel website on a Ubuntu server,

> Package egeloen/http-adapter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-ht
>   tp/httplug instead.

the above message appears when I try to run composer update.
I also tried `composer require egeloen/http-adapter` , but it shows new error massage now as follows.

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - infusionsoft/php-sdk 1.2.2 requires egeloen/http-adapter ~0.6 -> no matchi
>   ng package found.
>       - infusionsoft/php-sdk 1.2.2 requires egeloen/http-adapter ~0.6 -> no matchi
>   ng package found.
>       - infusionsoft/php-sdk 1.2.2 requires egeloen/http-adapter ~0.6 -> no matchi
>   ng package found.
>       - Installation request for infusionsoft/php-sdk == 1.2.2.0 -> satisfiable by
>   infusionsoft/php-sdk[1.2.2].

I'm new for these things,Thank You

Comment: it say  **- infusionsoft/php-sdk 1.2.2 requires egeloen/http-adapter ~0.6 -> no matching package found.** , can I add it manually?

Comment: Have you tried suggested package? `composer require php-http/httplug`?

Comment: No, I want to use egeloen/http-adapter, some of my other packages want it.